# Is DFS-Replication supported on a VHDX which resides on a CSV?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

DFS-Replication is not supported on CSVs but is it supported/acceptable to do DFS-R on a file server whose VHDX resides on a CSV?

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere.

We're running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this file server is a VM, who's disks are hosted on a CSV, then the answer is going to be yes.

Comment: Yeah, the file server is a Hyper-V VM running on a VHDX backended to a CSV. Good to know it is supported, thank you.